Does the statement $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \det(x) = 0$ have a truth value?
I couldn't think of anything specific for the question title so I just used an illustrative example.
Context
I often encounter the scenario where I have a set $X$ of objects for which a property $P$ is defined. But then I often have to prove (as some trivial case) that for some $Y \subset X$, $P(y)$ is true for all $y \in Y$. But it turns out that Y is empty and so I thought the result holds vacuously. But then I started thinking about properties and vacuous truths and had some questions. I haven't studied formal mathematical logic and would appreciate an answer for the 'working' mathematician.
Questions

From my understanding, any property $P$ has to be defined for a particular set of objects and evaluates to true or false for the objects for which it is defined. For example, let $P(x)$ be the property that $\det(x) = 0$. Then $P(x)$ would be undefined if $x$ is a real number since the determinant of a real number is undefined. Hence, a statement like $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, P(x)$ does not have a truth value. Is this correct?
But then are statements like $\forall x \in \emptyset, P(x)$ (where $P$ is any property) true (vacuously)? Are all properties automatically defined for the (nonexistent) elements of the empty set?

I believe I just have some severe misunderstandings and would appreciate it if anyone could help me resolve them.

Answer 1:  This is arguable, though I'd rather say that $\forall x\in\Bbb R;\det(x)=x$, so that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R};\det(x)=0$ has a truth value, namely: false. Answer 2: Yes.

Ok but if you didn't define what the determinant of a real number is then the statement  $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \det(x) = 0$ wouldn't make sense and hence not have a truth value right? Or is there some other convention for scenarios like this?

I agree. That is why I begun with "This is arguable".

Alright thanks. I have one more question: is there some sort of equivalency between vacuous truth and proof by contradiction? When I see a statement which is vacuously true (i.e. something like $\forall y \in Y , P(y)$ where $P$ is some property defined for all objects $x \in X$ and $Y$ is a subset of $X$ that turns out to be empty) I always mentally equated it with a proof by contradiction by supposing $\exists y' \in Y$ s.t. $\not P(y')$ which contradicts $Y$ being empty. Is this equivalency correct?

Actually now I realise the source of my asking this question. For the vacuously true statement $\forall x \in \emptyset, x + 1 = 0$, I tried to prove it by by contradiction by assuming there exists an $x \in \emptyset$ s.t. $x + 1 \neq 0$ which contradicts $x \notin \emptyset$ for all objects $x$. But the property  $x + 1 \neq 0$ does not make sense for any arbitrary object $x$ in $\emptyset$ right? So I suspect my thinking of proving a vacuously true statement using proof by contradiction as in the example above is flawed?

I thought it was more appropriate to ask my last question separately and have posted it as a separate question link. Thanks for all your help so far!

(1) Right.
(2) They are true, since you cannot find a $x\in\emptyset$ for which $P(x)$ is false. For the statement to be false, you need an element $x$ of $\emptyset$ for which $P(x)$ has a truth value, and is false. There isn't any and so the statement is true.
Hope this helps. :)

Isn't the second case just an application of ex falso quodlibet, because the statement $x\in\emptyset$ is already false for all $x$?

@paulina could you please elaborate?

@ultralegend5385 I can accept your explanation for (2) but wouldn't that imply that a statement like $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \det(x) = 0$ is true? Since according to your explanation, for the statement to be false there has to be an element $x \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\det(x) = 0$ has a truth value and is false but the property $\det(x) = 0$ is not defined for all real numbers and so there is no such $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

@gfjfvhjk: Neither of the statements $\forall x\in\Bbb R:,\det(x)=0$ and $\forall x\in\Bbb R:,\det(x)\neq0$ have a truth value.

@gfjfvhjk I'm not an expert on (mathematical) logic, but the link I provided should explain it
